# Google Sheets Script / Dynamically Add Formula

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying append some daily values to a sheet but can't quite figure out how to capture the current cell in a variable and then reuse it to generate the formula.

This is the code that I'm using

```
var emptyA = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1)
var emptyB = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,2,1)
var emptyC = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,3,1)
```

I'd like multiply the daily value in the A column with the value in cell F5 which also updates daily, because this changes it should be a formula so I figure it's something along the lines of

```
var dailyValue = sheet.getRange('F5')
var lastA = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),2,1)
var formula = "=" + lastA + "*" + dailyValue

emptyB.setFormula([formula])
```

The problem that I'm having is lastA gives me "RANGE" rather than the cell ID

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Cheers, Rich

Comment: Change to:

var dailyValue = sheet.getRange('F5').getValue
var lastA = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),2).getValue

emptyB.setFormula(formula)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to change

`var formula = "=" + lastA + "*" + dailyValue`

to

`var formula = "=" + "F5" + "*" + dailyValue.getA1Notation();`

---

Use `getA1Notation()` to return cell address like `A500`.

Use `getValue()` if you need the value to be hardcoded instead of a link to cell.

Comment: This was exactly correct, just what I needed - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change the following lines:

```
var dailyValue = sheet.getRange('F5').getValue
var lastA = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),2).getValue

emptyB.setFormula(formula)
```